# Jhipster - how to manage jwt revocation?

Tags: jwt, jhipster

Very nice talk on @devoxx fr !
I have a question about the release 3.0... 
Is there a revocation for the jwt token ? How do you manage it ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No as the token is not persisted. Currently you can only block a User not her token, token is valid for one day per default. If you want to revoke a token before it expires, you must persist generated tokens in the database and implement either a white list or a black list.

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks for reply.
In my case, i can't let the session alive all the time...
Whats the best way to manage the revocation ? Blacklist for tokens, persist the token in cache with idle time,... other way ? 
Is there a solution to do it without leaving the stateless architecture ?

Comment: You don't use servlet session when using JWT in JHipster, so I don't understand your point about staying stateless. By the way, this is not a good practice to use answers for commenting and maybe this is why some poeple did downvote your question.

Comment: I dont want to use servlet session but jwt token (to be stateless). The problem is i need revocation

Comment: White list approach: you save generated tokens in database, when you want to revoke a token before expiration you remove it from database and you check token on each request with some caching if you're afraid of hitting database too much. Black list approach, if you want to revoke a token you put save it in the database revoked list, caching also can be used. Nothing special here. You must manage daily purges also.

Comment: Ok thx but... its seems to be the same as httpSessions in distributed cache, with more complications. I wonder the right way is : if you need revocations, dont use jwt...

Comment: No it's very different but it's not the place for discussion, my answer is correct, so please consider accepting it.

Comment: Right it's not the place... because its about jwt and not jhipster. But if you want to be stateless and full fault tolerant, use persist (in my opinion) is not the right way. So about my first question , i could consider accept but i'm frustrated...

Comment: Feel free to use gitter to discuss the subject further https://gitter.im/jhipster/generator-jhipster